# access by index after *ptr1++ = *ptr2++

Tags: c++, pointers

This is how my code looks like:

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = {1,23,5,56,7,5};
    int *p2 = a;
    size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    int *p1 = new int[size];

    cout << "sizeof " << size << endl;
    int i = 0;
    while(p2 != a+size )
    {
        *p1++ = *p2++;
    }
    cout << p1[1] << ' ' << p1[3];
    return 0;
}
```

`cout << p1[1] << ' ' << p1[3];` outputting me values which are not the same as in a[1] and a[3]. Can anyone explain me why this is happening ?

Comment: *p1++ = *p2++ makes no sense. Assignment to temporary

Comment: @Andrew: It makes perfect sense.  It's not assignment to a temporary.  If it said `p1++ = p2++`, that would be assignment to a temporary.  But it's perfectly valid to assign to a dereferenced temporary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `while` loop modifies `p1`. After the loop is done, `p1` will point to the end of the new array (in fact, it'll point to the next position *after* the end). To solve the problem, keep a copy of the original `p1`.

```
int *p = p1;
while(p2 != a+size )
{
    *p1++ = *p2++;
}
p1 = p;
cout << p1[1] << ' ' << p1[3];
```

Comment: so after loop the `p1[1] ` statement equal to `*(p1+size+2)` ?

Comment: Right. And remember, since arrays are zero indexed the range of the array is 0-(size-1), so even `p1[0]` is out of range.

Answer (score 3):

You need to reset p1 to the begining of the initial array.

Answer (score 1):

After the loop,  `p1` points to the end of allocated buffer, not at the beginning, as in each iteration it is incremented.

You should try something like this:

```
int *p1 = new int[size];

int *begin = p1; //store the beginning of the array
while(p2 != a+size )
{
    *p1++ = *p2++;
}
p1 = begin; //reset to the begin again

//now print!
cout << p1[1] << ' ' << p1[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should reset p1 before accessing elements:

```
int main()
{
  int a[] = {1,23,5,56,7,5};
  int *p2 = a;
  int size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
  int *p1 = new int[size];

  cout << "sizeof " << size << endl;
  int i = 0;
  while(p2 != a+size )
  {
     *p1++ = *p2++;
  }
  p1 -= size;
  cout << p1[1] << ' ' << p1[3];
  return 0;
}
```